# Why does my close button wobble in some browsers?

Tags: css, css-transforms

Please checkout the demo at - http://jsfiddle.net/cYGzC/

The idea is that on hover the cross ('×') will turn around its center which will give a nice spinning motion on hover. The problem is, for this to work nicely the center of the × and the circle's center must coincide.

```
.close_button {
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(150,150,150,0.9);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The above CSS trickery seems to do the job in many browsers except Chrome in Windows. (The Mac Chrome seems to work fine.)

Comment: Chrome in windows works fine for me.

Comment: Works fine in chrome for me too but in the latest version of firefox it moves by one pixel then spins making it spin off center

Comment: For me it wobbles very noticeably in Chrome for Windows. Maybe font or other factors are at play here.

Comment: @AppleGrew Is there any reason why you're not using an image?

Comment: Yep Chrome for Windows is working for me. Would operating systems make a difference? I'm using Windows 8.

Comment: @KevinBrydon No not really. Yes I think I can do that too.

Comment: @Mattios550 Maybe. I am using WinXp.

Comment: Welcome to font rendering issue. NEVER use fonts for pixel perfect. Too much dependence on OS/browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is to use an image for your cross. As Taras says, there is no guarantee that fonts will be rendered exactly the same in every browser.

Comment: too bad that somebody downvoted this; +1 for the correct answer

Comment: @alex-shesterov Haters gonna hate!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `font-family` It causing part of the issue. If you make the `font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;` it seems to work better in firefox

http://jsfiddle.net/cYGzC/1/

Comment: Well it makes it worse for me in FF for WinXP. :P So I guess using a background image is the only sure way.

Comment: I admit that using Arial does not make the X centered perfectly but it stops the initial jump. however when you look at it in chrome its jumped off center more than firefox. I think the biggest problem it that each of the browsers treat the fonts differently in how they display the font in the browser. Is there a way to reset a font so it is the exact same in each browser?